# <pre> in fieldset doesn't respect the "overflow: auto" directive

Tags: html, css

This is a test case:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 950px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 660px">
            <form><fieldset>
            <pre style="overflow: auto">Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test Test test test </pre>
            </fieldset></form>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; width: 260px">
            Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the code in `<pre>` to show a scroll bar instead of overflowing into the "Lorem Ipsum" sidebar. If it's in a `<fieldset>` (as in the example) it overflows.

If you remove the `<form><fieldset>` it won't overflow anymore, but it won't show the scrollbar either (the overflowed text is simply clipped).

Here is what I want:

- If the text in the `<pre>` is longer than the available width it shouldn't overflow into "Lorem Ipsum" and it should show a scroll bar, whether it is in a `<fieldset>` or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obeying it, but in the context of it's default behavior.  It doesn't have a `width` currently, and the default behavior of a `<pre>` is to *not* have a width (but rather to expand into available space...and *it's parent* is willing to expand to accommodate it) so it's acting correctly.

If you *want* it to fit, just give it the same width as the parent, like this:

```
<pre style="overflow: auto; width: 660px;">
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but it still doesn't have a scrollbar. =(

Comment: @norepro - Is this example not working for you?  http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/B4srq/ If not, which browser are you seeing this in?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Firefox (3.6.8); I tried with chrome too, and with chrome it works.

Comment: @norepro - I think this may be as consistent as you'll get (with just CSS) cross-browser: http://jsfiddle.net/B4srq/1/ This *always* shows the scrollbar though.